# Gradient fill of a function inside a circular area Matlab

Tags: matlab, gradient

I'm trying to create a gradient fill inside a circular area according to a given function. I hope the plot below explains it at best

[image]
I'm not sure how to approach this, as in the simulation I'm working on the direction of the gradient changes (not always in the x direction as below, but free to be along all the defined angles), so I'm looking for a solution that will be flexible in that manner as well.

The code I have is below

```
    clear t
N=10;
for i=0:N 
    t(i+1) = 0+(2*i*pi) / N;
end
F = exp(-cos(t))./(2.*pi*besseli(1,1));
figure(1)
subplot(1,3,1)
plot(t*180/pi,F,'-ob')
xlim([0 360])
xlabel('angle')
subplot(1,3,2)
hold on
plot(cos([t 2*pi]), sin([t 2*pi]),'-k','linewidth',2);
plot(cos([t 2*pi]), sin([t 2*pi]),'ob');
plot(cos(t).*F,sin(t).*F,'b','linewidth',2);
subplot(1,3,3)    
hold on
plot(cos([t 2*pi]), sin([t 2*pi]),'-k','linewidth',2);
plot(cos([t 2*pi]), sin([t 2*pi]),'ob');
```

Comment: As I see it here you have a function of 2 variables, which in turn calculate a third (something like F(x,y)). Then any colourmap will colour along the third dimension, probably colouring your gradient.

Comment: @Adriaan, not exactly, it is even simpler. The function is defined soley by the values at the perimeter (blue circles), therefore if the gradient for example is along the x axis, the function is only of x.

Comment: What is the issue? Filling an area from its boundary values? That is non-trivial (and non-unique) so you need to define yourself how to do it. If the plotting is an issue, generating a meshgrid with values and using `imagesc` should work

Comment: have you looked at the `patch` graphics object? You can define several polygons, define a value/color for vertices, edges and surface with a number of interpolation options.

Comment: I don't understand the second (intermediate) mapping plot. From the first plot i get that you want to attach a color to a value of the curve ... but how does that project to your circle in the third picture ? ... and where do you calculate a gradient ?

Comment: @AnderBiguri, if you have any suggestions you are welcome to post an answer, as I have not resolved it yet.

Comment: @jarhead I'd need my question answered then

Comment: @jarhead would you please post a full answer based on the idea you liked?

Comment: @Dev-iL, yes, just working around the details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fill surface, you need to use the [patch](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html#buscm5g-1) command.

```
t = linspace(0, 2*pi, 100);
x = cos(t);
y = sin(t);
c = x; % colored following x value and current colormap

figure
patch(x,y,c)
hold on
scatter(x,y)
hold off
colorbar
```

Resulting graph:

[image: Result]

Colors are defined in c per point, and are interpolated inside the shape, so I'm sure that you should have all freedom to color as you want!

For example, the rotated version:

```
t = linspace(0, 2*pi, 100);
x = cos(t);
y = sin(t);
c = cos(t+pi/4) 

figure
patch(x,y,c)
colorbar
```

[image]

To understand how it is going on, just think that every point has a color, and matlab interpolate inside. So here I just rotated the intensity per point by pi /4.

For this to work you need to have a filled shape, and you may need to customize the color (c) parameter so that it matches your need. For example, if your gradient direction is encoded in a vector, you want to project all your point onto that vector to get the value along the gradient for all points.

For example:

```
% v controls the direction of the gradient
v = [0.1, 1];

t = linspace(0, 2*pi, 100);
F = exp(-cos(t))./(2.*pi*besseli(1,1));

% reconstructing point coordinate all around the surface
% this closes the path so with enough points so that interpolation works correctly
pts = [[t', F']; [t(end:-1:1)', ones(size(t'))*min(F)]];

% projecting all points on the vector to get the color
c = pts * (v');
clf
patch(pts(:,1),pts(:,2),c)
hold on
scatter(t, F)
hold off
```

[image]

Comment: this is great, but how can you rotate the gradient to a different angle?